# Defining AngularJS code inside ng-app declaration

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a SharePoint admin experimenting with AngularJS.  I am working on a page that will include several AngularJS applications in separate parts of the page. Each application is defined in a separate include file, so the javascript will be embedded in the body of the page.  Because of the issues surrounding multiple applications on a page, I figured, let's set up the Master Page to have a single ng-app declaration.

```
<body ng-app="SharePointAngApp">
```

As I said, the code definition is inside the body tag insert using a Content Editor Web Part.

```
var AngularApp = angular.module('SharePointAngApp',[]);
AngularApp.controller('spStockTicker',function($scope, $http) {
```

and

```
var JCAngularApp = angular.module('SharePointAngApp',['ngSanitize']);
JCAngularApp.controller('spJimConnect',['$scope','$http','$sce',function($scope, $http,$sce) {
```

However, now I'm getting an error: `angular.min.js:107 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/ng/areq?p0=spJimConnect&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined`

Is this possible, or does the javascript have to sit outsite the ng-app container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare the same module name twice.

You would be best off to include a second(or more) module as dependency of the main one

```
var AngularApp = angular.module('SharePointAngApp',['SharePointAngApp-2']);
var JCAngularApp = angular.module('SharePointAngApp-2',['ngSanitize']);
```

Also  the way you are needing to do this you may need to consider manually bootstrapping the app rather than using ng-app

That would allow you to build dependency arrays on as as needed basis

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks.